# Is it a good idea to disallow dedicated golfing languages?

Tags: discussion

I find that generally questions are answered by the same few users, with the same few languages. Is it a good idea to disallow dedicated golfing languages, to make the challenge fairer and more interesting?

*Note: I have attempted this and got heavily downvoted.*

Answer (score 4):

## No

Any language that <strike>is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)</strike> can add numbers and check if a number is prime is valid on PPCG, and since most golfing languages are Turing complete, they can do so.

Also, banning them only makes sense if you compare between languages, and comparing between languages doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: We actually don't require Turing completeness; we only require that the language can add numbers and check for primality. See [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/20469).